# Does ClearRect on a canvase context slow down the code over time?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I start the code, watch in dev window, get no errors. The image moves very quickly at first but, after a few seconds, it comes to a craw.

I checked on here but I can't figure it out. I'm a rookie so that could be the problem.

I've tried breaking it out into basic functional steps rather than any class, put "===" and "==" back and forth (cause I do not get the real difference between them), and changed from a "setInterval" to a "setTimeout" just in case I was calling the interval too soon.

I am very much a noob to Javascript and this is my first real work with canvas.

The HTML code simply adds the script with nothing else. The window load at the end of the script runs "startgame".

Thanks for anything you can help me with.

```
var winX=0;
var winY=0;
var scaleX=0;
var scaleY=0;
var bkcolor="#777777";
var ctx;
var objs=[];
var wallimg = new Image();
wallimg.src = 'wall.png';
var willy=new Image();
willy.src='willy.gif';
var player;
var gameActive=0;
var keyboard=[];
function startGame()
{
  var i;
  setWindow();
  theBoard.start();
  gameActive=1;
  someting=new Obj(0,10,600,20,"PATTERN",wallimg);
  someting.setimage(wallimg);
  Obj.Wall(40,100,100,16,wallimg);
  Obj.Wall(0,420,620,16,wallimg);
  Obj.Wall(0,0,16,440,wallimg);Obj.Wall(584,0,16,440,wallimg);
  player=new Obj(24,400,16,16,"PLAYER",willy);
  player.setimage(willy);
  player.gravity=1;
}
function setWindow()
{
  winX = window.innerWidth|| document.documentElement.clientWidth|| document.body.clientWidth;
  winY = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.body.clientHeight;
  winX=winX-4;
  winY=winY-4;
  scaleX=640/winX;
  scaleY=480/winY;
  if (gameActive==1) {
      theBoard.canvas.width = 600/scaleX;
      theBoard.canvas.height = 440/scaleY;
      theBoard.canvas.style.left=""+20/scaleX+"px";
      theBoard.canvas.style.top=""+20/scaleY+"px";
    }
}
function setBackdrop(img)
{
  var str="<img src='"+img+"' onclick='showCoords(event);' style='";
  str=str+"width:"+winX+"px;height:"+winY+"px;'>";
  document.getElementById('page').innerHTML=str;
  document.getElementById('page').innerHTML=str;
  currimage=img;
}
var theBoard = {
    canvas : theCanvas=document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600/scaleX;
        this.canvas.height = 440/scaleY;
        this.canvas.style.left=""+20/scaleX+"px";
        this.canvas.style.top=""+20/scaleY+"px";
        this.canvas.style.position="absolute";
        this.canvas.tabIndex=1;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx=this.context;
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.canvas.style.backgroundColor=bkcolor;
        setTimeout(updateGameArea, 40);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            keyboard=(keyboard||[]);
            keyboard[e.keyCode]=(e.type=="keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            keyboard[e.keyCode]=(e.type=="keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
      
    },    
    restart:function() { this.interval = setTimeout(updateGameArea, 40);},
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
function updateGameArea()
{
  var i;
  theBoard.clear();
  if (keyboard && keyboard[37])
  {
    player.speed-=2; if (player.speed<-8) player.speed=-8;
  }
  else if (player.speed<0)
  {
    player.speed+=1;
  }
  if (keyboard && keyboard[39])
  {
    player.speed+=2; if (player.speed>8) player.speed=8;
  }
  else if (player.speed>0)
  {
    player.speed-=1; 
  }
  if (player.gravity<1) player.gravity++;
  if (keyboard && keyboard[38] && player.gravity>-1 && player.canjump==1){ 
    player.gravity=-16;
    player.dir=-6;
    player.canjump=0;
  }
  if (player.gravity<4) {player.gravity=player.gravity+player.dir; player.dir+=4;if (player.dir>16) player.dir=16;}
  if (player.gravity!=0)
  {
    player.y+=player.gravity;
    if (checkWalls(player)==true)
    {  player.y-=player.gravity;
      if (player.gravity>0) player.canjump=1;
    }
  }  
  if (player.speed!=0)
  {
    player.x+=player.speed;
    if (checkWalls(player)===true)
      player.x-=player.speed;
  }
  for (i=0;i<objs.length;i++)
    objs[i].draw();
  setTimeout(updateGameArea, 10);
}
function checkWalls(obj)
{
  var i;
  for (i=0;i<objs.length;i++)
  {
    if (objs[i].type=="WALL")
      if (obj.collision(objs[i])) {return true;}
  }
  return false;
}
class Obj {
  constructor (x,y,w,h,t,img="") {
    this.width=w;
    this.height=h;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.type=t;
    this.imagemap=img;
    this.speed=0;
    this.gravity=0;
    this.dir=0;
    this.canjump=1;
    this.pattern=0;
    objs[objs.length]=this;
    }
  static Wall(x,y,w,h,img) {
    var id=new Obj(x,y,w,h,"WALL",img);
    return id;
    }
  draw() 
  {
    if ((this.x/scaleX)<0 || (this.x/scaleX)>theBoard.canvas.width || 
        (this.y/scaleY)<0 || (this.y/scaleY)>theBoard.canvas.height)
      return;
    switch (this.type){
      case 'PATTERN':
      case 'WALL':
      {
        if (this.pattern===0)
        { this.pattern=ctx.createPattern(this.imagemap,"repeat");}
        ctx.rect(this.x/scaleX,this.y/scaleY,this.width/scaleX,this.height/scaleY);
        ctx.fillStyle=this.pattern;
        ctx.fill();
        break;
      }
      case 'PLAYER':
        ctx.drawImage(this.imagemap,0,0,this.width,this.height,this.x/scaleX,this.y/scaleY,this.width/scaleX,this.height/scaleY);
        break;
      
    }
  }
  setimage(img)
  {
    this.imagemap=img;
  }
  collision(wth) {
    if (((this.x+this.width)>wth.x) && (this.x<(wth.x+wth.width))
      && ((this.y+this.height)>wth.y) && (this.y<(wth.y+wth.height)))
      {return true;}
    else return false;
  }
}
window.onload=startGame();
```

Comment: For rendering loops use `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Concerning: `==` vs `===`: Always use `===` (or do something like `![] == []` and be surprised)

Comment: "does clearRect slow down over time?" nope. This is something in your code. Might visit the performance tab of your browser and get used to it ...

Comment: changed to requestAnimationFrame, no change. changed all == to === and all != to !==. no change. Performance continually drops over time to about 3 frames. maybe a garbage collection? i dunno. haven't coded in a very long time.

Comment: I took out the pattern fill (using just a fillrect) from the wall/pattern type and all the performance issues went away. The solutions here are helpful. Will need to figure out why the fill style hangs. Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: beginpath and endpath fixed the fill style hangs. Thanks again!  @N3R4ZZuRR0, your info was awesome! I'll be a real javascript programmer some day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Kaiido, solution to your problem is here: [HTML5 Canvas performance very poor using rect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653905/html5-canvas-performance-very-poor-using-rect).

In short, just put your main loop code between `beginPath` and `closePath` without changing your `theBoard.clear()` method.

```
function updateGameArea()
{
    var i;
    theBoard.clear();
    theBoard.context.beginPath();
    ...
    theBoard.context.closePath();
    requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
}
```

**Answer I originally wrote:**

Resetting the dimensions to clear the canvas works better in your case, **but it would induce performance issues.**

```
clear : function() {
    this.context.canvas.width = 600 / scaleX;
    this.context.canvas.height = 440 / scaleY;
}
```

Also, use `requestAnimationFrame` as it eliminates any flicker that can happen when using `setTimeout`.

```
requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
```

Comment: That's the worse way to clear a canvas, this will not only clear the context and all its properties, it will also reassign (a) new internal bitmap(s).

Comment: @Kaiido Might be. But in this case, clearing the canvas this way is actually solving the issue of canvas slowing down.

Comment: Because it will incidentally also reset the current path, but that's not the proper solution, which you can find in the [linked Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653905/html5-canvas-performance-very-poor-using-rect).

Comment: ... No no, I got my gold badge in a corn flakes box... As I said, resetting the canvas size will not only clear the canvas, it will also clear all the properties of the context and will even reassign (a) new internal bitmap(s). So YES it will cause issues like huge perfs drop and GC kicking in for nothing.

Comment: So, what could be the best possible performance friendly solution in this case?

Comment: ... It's written in the answer to the [linked Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653905/html5-canvas-performance-very-poor-using-rect) this question is a duplicate of: `beginPath`

Comment: @Kaiido Okay. Thanks for the enlightenment. I was doing this the wrong way since a long time. Never felt much of a performance impact, so never considered it as a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a guess. I think you're running out of cycles and your frames are piling up on top of each other. At a glance, I don't see anything in your code that would cause a memory leak. Unless you look at the console memory graph and find out that you do, because you're adding listeners over and over or something like that. But simply clearing a canvas does not slow things down. It's basically the same as setting a bunch of values in an array.

However: Running heavy canvas operations within a setTimeout() can have a big toll on your CPU, if the CPU can't finish one operation before the next one enters the queue. Remember that timeouts are asynchronous. If your CPU throttles down and if the refresh rate you are specifying (40 milliseconds) is too short, then you will be left with a whole stack of redraws and clears that are waiting to go right after the last one, without giving the CPU any time to breathe.

Most Canvas animation packages have ways of dealing with this, by not just setting a timeout but waiting to make sure the last redraw is finished before triggering the next one in the call stack, and dropping a frame if necessary. At a bare minimum, you want to set a global variable like `_redrawing=true` before you do your redraw, and then set it to false when the redraw is finished, and ignore any call to setTimeout while it's still true. That will let you count how many frames you might be dropping. If you see this number going up over time, your CPU may be throttling as well. But do also check the memory graph and see if anything else is leaking.

**Edit** as correctly noted by @N3R4ZZuRR0 using `requestAnimationFrame()` will also avoid the timer problem. But you then need to measure the time between animation frames to figure out where things should actually be at that point in time. My suggestion of dropping frames here and there is primitive and most packages use `requestAnimationFrame()`, but it would help you identify whether your problem is with some other part of your code or with your frames building up in the timer.